# Azure Monitor - How to create an alert when a new subscription is created?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I would like to create an alert on Azure when someone create a new subscription. I would like to use Azure Monitor but I need to fill the subscription name to create an Azure Monitor alert... Do you use a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

The alert is a resource in a specific subscription, it can just monitor the resource in the subscription. The subscription is under the Azure AD tenant, the tenant is not a resource in the subscription, the alert is unable to monitor it.

Comment: Thanks @Joy Wang. So there is no other way to raise an alert when a new subcription is created ?

Comment: @Themis AFAIK, there is no such way. The closest is to use this rest api [Tenant Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/tenantactivitylogs/list) to see the logs, it should include the information.